# implement suggestions and select it for firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart

**i want to add suggestions/autocomplete list in field for show firestore data and choose from suggestion list to complete the field**,

i try to use several packages to achieve that like flutter_typeahead,
but  it work for local list (*Commodity1*) but it won't work for firestore data (*Commodity2*)... any help please?

my code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _selectedCommodity1;
  var _selectedCommodity2;
  TextEditingController commodityFiled1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController commodityFiled2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("QFS"),
            ),
            body: Form(
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 5, bottom: 10, right: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      TypeAheadFormField(
                        textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                            controller: commodityFiled1,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Commodity1',
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.receipt_rounded,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                ))),
                        suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
                          return CommodityService.getSuggestions(pattern);
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (context, String suggestion) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(suggestion),
                          );
                        },
                        transitionBuilder:
                            (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
                          return suggestionsBox;
                        },
                        onSuggestionSelected: (String suggestion) {
                          commodityFiled1.text = suggestion;
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) => _selectedCommodity1 = value!,
                      ),
                      TypeAheadFormField(
                        textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                            controller: commodityFiled2,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Commodity2',
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.receipt_rounded,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                ))),
                        suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
                          return getSuggestion(pattern);
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(suggestion.toString()),
                          );
                        },
                        transitionBuilder:
                            (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
                          return suggestionsBox;
                        },
                        onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
                          commodityFiled2.text = suggestion.toString();
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) => _selectedCommodity2 = value!,
                      ),
                    ])))));
  }

  static getSuggestion(String suggestion) async =>
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("QFS")
          .where('commodity', isEqualTo: suggestion)
          .get()
          .then((snap) {
        return snap.docs;
      });
}

class CommodityService {
  static final List<String> commodity = [
    'Banana',
    'Mango',
    'Orange',
  ];

  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = [];
    matches.addAll(commodity);
    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }
}
```

image for my firstore collection: https://nimb.ws/1tKDQb

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Firestore with keywords. So basically whenever get the search keyword (on a keypress or using debounce) from the user, you can filter the Firestore docs and show the relevant suggestions with the list you get back as a response.

To learn more on querying with Firestore with where checkout: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#filtering

Comment: foe more info see my code please i add it